# Pandas modify column values in place based on boolean array

Tags: python, pandas

I know how to create a new column with `apply` or `np.where` based on the values of another column, but a way of selectively changing the values of an existing column is escaping me; I suspect `df.ix` is involved? Am I close?

For example, here's a simple dataframe (mine has tens of thousands of rows). I would like to change the value in the 'flag' column (let's say to 'Blue') if the name ends with the letter 'e':

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Mick', 'John', 'Christine', 'Stevie', 'Lindsey'], \
        'flag':['Purple', 'Red', nan, nan, nan]})[['name', 'flag']]
>>> print df

        name    flag
0       Mick  Purple
1       John     Red
2  Christine     NaN
3     Stevie     NaN
4    Lindsey     NaN
[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

I can make a boolean series from my criteria:

```
>boolean_result = df.name.str.contains('e$')
>print boolean_result
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: name, dtype: bool
```

I just need the crucial step to get the following result:

```
>>> print result_wanted
        name    flag
0       Mick  Purple
1       John     Red
2  Christine    Blue
3     Stevie    Blue
4    Lindsey     NaN
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
df['flag'][df.name.str.contains('e$')] = 'Blue'
```

Comment: That's exactly it! I was totally overthinking it; once again, pandas is elegant where I assume it has to be complicated. Thanks!

Comment: I thought this kind of chained assignment was not recommended? I pretty much always use .loc when I found some very odd effects of this kind of assignment. I mean it clearly works here, but in general I was under the impression this is to be avoided. Is that your understanding?

Comment: @WoodyPride For indexing with boolean vectors this is perfectly fine, if you want to add in other forms of indexing you would want `loc`. For instance: `df.loc[df.name.str.contains('e$'), 'flag'] = 'Blue'`. You are right to be concerned about views vs copies. Reversing the order of access (for me) gives an error: `df[df.name.str.contains('e$')]['flag'] = 'Blue'`

Comment: Indeed, when I use this method on a real data with a long regex with in [ab]c|d[ef] formulation, pandas returns a warning that I might want to use str.extract. In this case, it's all right because I want any record that fits any pattern to have the same label, but I can see why one needs to be careful using this method.

Comment: Just to add, I'm relatively experienced with pandas and I get semantically confused with R, but U2EF1s first solution 'looks' like a dict assignment, so it seems to be a view not a copy. In pandas, I'm more used to dealing in copies, which is why I couldn't conceptualize the way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

[`DataFrame.mask(cond, other=nan)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) does exactly things you want.

It replaces values with the value of `other` where the condition is True.

```py
df['flag'].mask(boolean_result, other='blue', inplace=True)
```

`inplace=True` means to perform the operation in place on the data.

If you want to replace value on condition false, you could consider using [`DataFrame.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html).